# Gitblit services not started

Tags: gitblit

After the execution of batch file in Gitblit, gitblit service won't start.

1. Install Java 7
2. Install Gitblit GO in Win 7 - 64 bit machine
3. Goto service and view the service status.

Win 7 - gitblit GO-1.3.2 - jdk-7u51-windows-x64

gitblit service is required to open the gitblit in browser?

Based on this following site, i exected the gitblit batch files.

http://gitblit.com/setup_go.html

Kindly let me know, what else i need to do.

Regards,
Sathishkumar Pannerselvam

Comment: same here, windows service is not working with jre8, jdk8, jre7, jre8x86. tried also with both ARCH setups. the thing is http is working, https not. if i run the gitblit.cmd, everything works just fine

Answer (score 0):

Service isn't required to start Gitblit.

On Windows Envrionnement : you can use the batch script `gitblit.cmd` to start it. But don't forget the configuration's step in the file ***gitblit.properties*** (server.httpPort...). After you can access Gitblit with this url *http:\localhost:8080*

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem.
But I solved as follows:

1. Open `installService.cmd` with text editor like notepad.
2. In line 12, I changed `SET ARCH=amd64` into `SET ARCH=x86`. (The architecture of my computer is **x86**.)
3. Run `installService.cmd` by double-clicking it or run `installService` in Command Prompt.

Answer (score 0):

CD may not be found .Try to add CD definition:

```
@REM arch = x86, amd64, or ia32
SET ARCH=amd64
SET CD=E:/gitblit-1.8.0
```

It may work.